# FetchedResultsController-problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

i've got a problem, that drives me crazy. I guess it should be fairly easy to solve, but i don't get it...

I'm trying to setup a tableview with a fetchedResultsController, but for some reason the frc is returning a section-count of zero. Here is my code for the frc:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Kundendaten" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Kundenname" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"Kundenname" cacheName:@"Root"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self._fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And here i'm trying to get the section-count:

```
int count = [[[self fetchedResultsController] sections] count];
```

// at this point the count-variable is 0. the following is just to prove, that my moc isnt empty... Even if i set the sectionNameKeyPath to nil, it returns 0.

```
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                              entityForName:@"Kundendaten" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setEntity:entityDescription];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"Kundenname" ascending:YES];
    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *array = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    count = [array count];

    return count;
```

In this case, the count is 5...

Does someone see, where the problem is?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, looks like you've set up the fetch nicely, but you should probably actually DO the fetch....

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![aFetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
     NSLog(@"Bad Fetch %@", error);
 }
```